# Can I change the Bluetooth identifier for an EV3 brick?

Tags: ev3, bluetooth

I'm coaching a number of FIRST Lego League teams and wish to set up our lab so that each computer could potentially be paired with each brick, but I want to uniquely identify the bricks (EV3-Team1, EV3-Team2, etc). Is there a way to change the brick's Bluetooth name?

Answer (score 6):

I'm teaching an after school robotics program and the kids are using the LEGO MindStorms Education Core Set #45544. I was dealing with the same situation when I had to connect 10 EV3s to Bluetooth or Wi-Fi and I couldn't distinguish from one EV3 to the next.  Anyhow, I figured out how easy it was to give each brick it's own unique identifying name. You want to make sure that the EV3 is connected to the computers via USB cable and that the LEGO MindStorms program is opened. In the bottom right corner of the screen, you'll see the hardware page. Click on the brick info and then just change the name.  See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in the NXT 3.0 software itself. Connect the robot to your PC, and in the software itself you can change it in the bottom right hand corner, above the firmware number and the connection type. Hope that helped.